# TSQL Cancel long running UPDATE without rolling back

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, query-optimization, rollback

I have no BEGIN / END and no TRANSACTION START.

```
  UPDATE [rpt].[Symbol_Index]
   SET [fk_company] = b.pk_company  --INT
  FROM [rpt].[Symbol_Index] A
  JOIN lu.company b
    ON a.[fmp_Y_SeriesSymbol] = b.[ticker]  --VARCHAR(18)
```

I'm resetting a logic key type of VARCHAR(18) to an  INT, assuming this to be more efficient for joins. This being the first step of the key reset.

this are about 5 Million rows and 16 hours seems too long. This is a case where I discover how un-DBA I really am.

Comment: Update: I resized the VM and forced a shutdown. SQL Server came up in 'In Recovery' for the database I had 16 hours worth of updates ran. I conclude that I will not be keeping those updates and will have to start over?

Comment: The update was done in an autocommit transaction. Since the update did not complete, it will rolled back by crash recovery. You might find it faster to restore from backup, if that is an option. It is often best to perform large updates in multiple smaller batches.

Comment: Personally, I would [race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) before assuming int will be significantly more efficient for joins. Premature optimization is the root of much evil.

Comment: @DanGuzman usually it's only faster when there is other concurrent usage, otherwise it will be slower than just doing it in one batch. But as you say, having a look at the indexes and the query plan first may help us

Comment: @Charlieface, in addition to improving concurrency, a batching technique can be faster when the amount of data updated exceeds the buffer pool size. Not suggesting that's the case here.

Comment: @DanGuzman Didn't know that. Aaron Bertrand has [an article](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/03/io-subsystem/chunk-deletes) albeit on deletes, and didn't mention that point, looking at it I wonder if there may be an issue here constant t-log growth, instead of a fixed large size.

Comment: Have you examined the _estimated execution plan_? It's often the appropriate starting point for investigating performance issues. (The _actual_ execution plan would be better, but it isn't available until after the query has completed. Running the query on a subset of data that would allow timely completion might help, e.g. by adding a `where` clause to limit the range of `fmp_Y_SeriesSymbol` values.) Please see [paste the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/instructions/) for a way to include an execution plan in your question.

Comment: @HABO the actual execution plan should be available from [sys.dm_exec_query_plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-query-plan-transact-sql) as soon as query planning has finished and the query has started executing.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Actual row counts, I/O statistics and CPU usage are unlikely to be available before the query completes. Estimated values may point to opportunities to improve the query or incorrect assumptions in the query optimizer. [Live Query Statistics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/live-query-statistics?view=sql-server-ver15) might be of interest while the query is running.

Comment: I really appreciate the attention on this. Thank you all. It is my first time building such a large data set; learning curve.

Even with a Standard D32ds_v4 Azure VM, deleting half of 50 million records took 12 hours. Again, realizing I'm no DBA as I have no idea where to start in understanding how to improve that.